# Is there a thread safety issue possibly in this function?

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import kgapp

def extraction(content: str) -> Dict:
    
    logger.info('text: {}'.format(content))
    results = {'text': content}

    tokens = xlu.process(content)
    found = False
    data = []
    if 'entities' in tokens:
        for entity_key, entity_value in tokens['entities'].items():
            for entity in entity_value:
                records = kgapp.node_by_keyword(entity, limit=1)
                if records:
                    found = True
                keyword_hits = []
                for record in records:
                    curr_result = {}
                    curr_result['word'] = record['name']
                    curr_result['type'] = record['type']
                    keyword_hits.append(curr_result)
                data.append(keyword_hits)

    results['result'] = data
    results['status'] = 'success' if found else 'failed'

    return results
```

If this function 'extraction' is used with multithreading, is there any possibility of thread safety issue? If the two functions xlu.process() and kgapp.node_by_keyword() are thread safe, can I say 'extraction' is safe?

Comment: It looks like your function only really depends on its parameter, so it looks thread-safe. btw, curr_result does nothing.

Comment: Do you mutate something with out-of-function scope?

Comment: @LiorCohen what do you mean by out-of-function?

Comment: @quamrana I updated it and it does something now.

Comment: some global variable or object that the function gets not by its input. I did not find such. But asking as you know your code better.

Comment: @quamrana Also, if the 2 functions called are not thread safe, there could be an issue. Right?

Comment: @LiorCohen Yes. No other modified it.

Comment: Yes, it seems to come down to those other two functions.

Comment: so, like you were @quamrana told you, your code looks safe.

Comment: @LiorCohen If the two functions called inside are not safe, then it is going to be an issue?

Comment: potentially it can cause issues. it depends what is the side-effect of the "not safe". you can always wrap them by a `threading.Lock()` if you are suspect they might collide.

Comment: @LiorCohen could you please write an answer by using threading.Lock() in my example?